# Which is the way to get date and time through HTML 5

Tags: html, forms, date, time

I'm developing a web app where I should get time and date through a form. I have tried time but unfortunately it is not compatible with all browser. For example it doesn't work properly in Safari. So which is the best way to get date and time?

```
Select a time: <input type="time" name="usr_time">
```

this element doesn't work correctly on Safari

Comment: What you you mean, you've tried *time*, are we supposed to know what that is? You are asking for an opinion as it stands which is frowned upon in SO. You might want to reword things somewhat. Perhaps give an example of what you have coded and what was wrong in Safari asking for suggestions on how to improve it.

Comment: Sorry I didn't specifed anything

Comment: Just use two dropdown lists (<select> elements).  One for hours and another for the minutes.

Comment: What is best depends on opinions and on context, as well as on detailed requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The new HTML 5 input types are very [poorly supported](http://caniuse.com/input-datetime) right now.

Some options:

- You can leave the code as it is and sanity check the input with JavaScript.
- Use two input fields as suggested by @HaukurHaf
- Use a JavaScript library
- Write your own JavaScript

The quickest to get right would be to use a library that uses JavaScript to attach a script to the input field giving the user a better experience with perhaps a clock or other selector to help them.

For example, the JQuery based [Time Entry](http://keith-wood.name/timeEntry.html) helper by Keith Wood.